# Cannot see a class from another project even if referenced

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I have two projects in one solution. One contains forms and the other is a class library.

In that class library I have two classes: `TaskItem` and `TaskItemList`

and in order to use them from the other project I referenced them by `Add Reference`

Problem is that I **CAN** use `TaskItem` class but **CANNOT** use 'TaskItemList' class, as it is not seen by the project.

There must some trivial thing I am missing.

Please help :) thanks)

Comment: are these classes `public`?

Comment: Perhaps `TaskItemList` is not public?

Comment: Are all classes visible in the same namespace? I enclose all my classes in a "namespace MyProject".

Comment: It was just `class TaskItemList`, I thought default access modifier is `public`. Thanks for pointing out :) I know it was trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing your TaskItemList class would be private. If its public, include the class definitions in your question.

Comment: It was just `class TaskItemList`, I thought default access modifier is `public`. Thanks for pointing out :) I know it was trivial.

Comment: _"I am guessing"_ - that's what comments are for. Answers are for once the problem is clear.

Comment: I understand that CodeCaster but I did not have enough reputation for commenting on the question. :)

Comment: @Kavish you do now :)

Comment: @Kavish: You got lucky by having the right answer this time, but in case this is an issue in the future, please do not try to work around rep requirements by hacking up some other feature of the site. That just makes more work for others to clean up, and is almost never any good for you in the long run either.

Answer (score -1):

i would recommend declare the class as protected internal. hope that will help you...